# Could not create Appender [AdoNetAppender] of type [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, log4net] error

Tags: logging

I'm trying to patch an **AdoNetAppender** using the `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, log4net` appender by doing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <log4net>
            <appender name="AdoNetAppender" patch:after="*[@name='PublishingLogFileAppender']" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, log4net">
                <bufferSize value="1" />
                <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                <connectionStringName value="Log4netConnectionString" />
```

By enabling the [log4net internal debbuging](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug), I noticed the following error:

> log4net: DOMConfigurator: Loading Appender [AdoNetAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, log4net]
>
> log4net:ERROR DOMConfigurator: Could not create Appender [AdoNetAppender] of type [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, log4net]. Reported error follows.
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender' to type 'log4net.Appender.IAppender'.
>      at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.DOMHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
>
> log4net:ERROR DOMConfigurator: Appender named [AdoNetAppender] not found.

I wonder if Sitecore is trying to cast the `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, log4net` to type `log4net.Appender.IAppender, Sitecore.Logging`.

First question would be: Is it possible to use `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, log4net` appender?

I tried to use the `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, Sitecore.Logging` before, but it is very limited. e.g. there is not `RawPropertyLayout` and the `PatternLayout` doesn't work the same way as in the **log4net** assembly.

## Update 1

If I change the type to `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender` (without the `, log4net`) as below, I get errors such as `[log4net.Layout.PatternLayout] is not assignable to type [log4net.Layout.IRawLayout]`.

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" patch:after="*[@name='PublishingLogFileAppender']" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    [...]
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
            <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{yyyy&apos;-&apos;MM&apos;-&apos;dd HH&apos;:&apos;mm&apos;:&apos;ss&apos;.&apos;fff}" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
```

I believe it is due to the fact that I'm using `log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net` layouts.

> log4net:ERROR DOMConfigurator: Object type [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout] is not assignable to type [log4net.Layout.IRawLayout]. There are no acceptable type convertions.
>   log4net:ERROR DOMConfigurator: Failed to create object to set param: layout

Also, I get the following error:

> log4net:ERROR DOMConfigurator: Cannot find Property [connectionStringName] to set object on [log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender]

I believe Sitecore is assuming `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender, Sitecore.Logging` if I omit the **log4net** from the type.

Comment: Can you try with type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender"? Just checking a site where I have this working and that was the first difference.

Comment: @Gatogordo I tried it also, please see my **Update 1** above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I figure it out. Here's what I found out:

- Although `Sitecore.Logging` assembly uses the same log4net namespace, it doesn't depend on log4net at all. You can check it in the Sitecore **Assembly list** link in the **Release information** section of the [download page](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Update5.aspx) and also in the .zip installation file. i.e. you won't find a log4net assembly.
- `Sitecore.Logging` seems like a copy-and-paste from the original log4net but with fewer features. e.g. you don't have the `RawPropertyLayout` and the `PatternLayout` doesn't behave as the one in log4net (version 2.0.8).
- When you omit the "log4net" assembly name in the appender type, Sitecore assumes you are using an appender available at `Sitecore.Logging`. e.g. `log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender`.
- If you use the "log4net" assembly name in the appender type, Sitecore tries to parse it to `log4net.Appender.IAppender, Sitecore.Logging`, which obviously causes a parse error.

## How to work this around?

If you want to use the same features from log4net you have two options:

1) Create a custom appender/layout extending from  `log4net.Appender.IAppender, Sitecore.Logging` or `log4net.Appender.IRawLayout, Sitecore.Logging` and copy the code from the log4net.

2) Configure log4net separately by either adding a log4net.config file or a different one but referencing its location in the application settings.
e.g.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Config" value="App_Config/Company.Log4net.config"/>
  <add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True"/>
</appSettings>
```

See more about log4net configuration [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

Don't replace the log4net section in the web.config. Otherwise, the Sitecore logging will stop working.